# Magento Address template custom field

Tags: php, magento

Am creating custom address template to specify Destination type. Am trying to show address destination type as "Commercial" or "Residential" in Billing and Shipping address.

I've installed extension to validate customer address. Validated destination type is saved in `sales_flat_quote_address` table and extra `dest_type` field is added to save validated response.

Following are values saved in `dest_type` field.

- RES
- COM
- ASK_M

I've used below coding to check and display destination type in Billing and Shipping address.

My condition if `dest_type` is **COM** then it should display "Commercial", else if `dest_type` is **RES** then it should display "Residential", otherwise it should display "Not Specified"

> {{depend prefix}}
>   {{var prefix}}
>   {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}
>   {{depend company}}{{var company}}
> {{/depend}}
>   {{if street1}}{{var street1}}
> {{/if}}
>   {{depend street2}}{{var street2}}
> {{/depend}}
>   {{depend street3}}{{var street3}}
> {{/depend}}
>   {{depend street4}}{{var street4}}
> {{/depend}}
>   {{if city}}{{var city}},  {{/if}}{{if region}}{{var region}}, {{/if}}{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}}{{/if}}
>   {{var country}}
>   {{depend telephone}}T: {{var telephone}}{{/depend}}
>   {{depend fax}}
> F: {{var fax}}{{/depend}}
>   {{depend vat_id}}
> VAT: {{var vat_id}}{{/depend}}
> {{ifequal dest_type COM}}Commercial{{else}}Residential{{/ifequal}}

Above code does't helps me.What I missed? What should I do?

**Note:** Above code is given in System -> Configuration -> Customer Configuration -> Address Templates -> HTML field

Comment: ```ifequal``` is not a pattern recognized in Varien_Filter_Template in Magento pre 2 versions

Answer (score 0):

In admin area, Customer -> Attributes -> Manage Customer Address Attributes you can define a new attribute "Destination Type".

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply - I cant find an admin option for customer attributes - where abouts is that?